# how to submit checklist in Django with GET

Tags: python, django, web

Hi I have on my html file this, `tags` and `tagInfos` are both queryset´s of Django, that 2 for´s are only to show wich one belongs to the other:

```
<form action="/chart/chart/" method="get">
    {% if tags.count > 0 %}                     
        {% for tag in tags %}
            {% for tagInfo in tagInfos %}
                {% if tag.taginfo_idtaginfo1_id == tagInfo.idtaginfo %}
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{ tag.idtag }}" />
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% csrf_token %}            
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit creation</button>          
    {% else %}
        <p>None TAG to select.</p>      
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

So and on my view i try to do that:

```
def chart(request):
   if 'checks' in request.GET and request.GET['checks']:
      chosen = request.GET.getlist('checks')
      return render_to_response('Chart/chart.html',{'chosen':chosen})
   else: 
      return render_to_response('Chart/chart.html',{})
```

But don´t show any of the selected checkboxes on the other html, I´m using `{{ chosen }}` to show.

Any ideas of what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def chart(request):
   if 'checks[]' in request.GET:  #<----- 'checks[]'
      chosen = request.GET.getlist('checks[]')  #<----- 'checks[]'
      return render_to_response('Chart/chart.html',{'chosen':chosen})
   else: 
      return render_to_response('Chart/chart.html',{})
```